# Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression: no-unused-expressions

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, eslint

Why can't  I use Ternary with 2 statements here?

ESLInt Error: `no-unused-expressions`

```
res?.isSuccessful ?
   (this.toastService.showToast(res.message, 'success'), this.queueDataService.addMember(attendee)) :
              this.toastService.showToast(res.message, 'warning');
```

No ESLint Error

```
  res.isSuccessful ?
          (this.toastService.showToast(res.message, 'success')) :
          this.toastService.showToast(res.message, 'warning');
```

ESLInt

```
 "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-expressions": [
          "error",
          {
            "allowTernary": true,
           }
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplify your code first doing a split phase. First your toast then the effect.

```
this.toastService.showToast(res.message, res.isSuccessful ? 'success' : 'warning');

if (res.isSuccessful) {
  this.queueDataService.addMember(attendee);
}
```